# Bookmarklet Opens Empty Window

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, bookmarklet, bookmarks

Ok so I have a basic bookmarklet that opens remote websites.  However when I try to open my local dev site it just opens to a blank page.  I am assuming this has something to do with security etc.

I set the bookmarklet to open one of my remote sites, gnull.com - This worked fine.  I then set gnull.com to resolve to 127.0.0.1 and changed my bindings in IIS.  The result this time is that a new window opens however it is blank.  When I look at the headers being sent only one is created with a result of 'error' and a type of 'NS_ERROR_ABORT'.

I am using Firefox 4 on Windows 7.  Does anyone know how to setup bookmarklets for testing local sites?  The code itself works fine since I have tested this with other live websites so this appears to be a browser security feature.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to post the actual source code to your bookmarklet.

Comment: It was actually a conflict with the NOSCRIPT extension - it blocks scripts from accessing local resources - even if the site is allowed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comment, I found the issue was with ABE - a component of the noscript extension.  ABE blocks scripts from accessing local resources, in my case a local website.  I disabled ABE in the noscript options and everything works fine.